# connection string data source error

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, vb.net

in an aspx.vb file

```
Sub Button3_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click

        Dim con As New OleDbConnection("Provider= SQLOLEDB.1;Integrated Security=true; data source=myserver; ")

        Dim cmd As New OleDbCommand

        cmd.Connection = con
        cmd.CommandText = "Insert into demo.dbo.masters1 values ('" & TextBox1.Text & " ," & TextBox4.Text & " , " & TextBox3.Text & " ')"
        con.Open()
        If (cmd.ExecuteNonQuery() > 0) Then
            Label1.BorderColor = Drawing.Color.Aquamarine
        Else
            Label1.BorderColor = Drawing.Color.Black
        End If

        con.Close()

End Sub
```

I am using Windows Authentication.

The server is up and running.

I've also tried:

```
Dim con As New OleDbConnection("Provider= SQLOLEDB.1;Integrated Security=true; data source=C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10_50.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\database_name.mdf; ")
```

However, I'm getting the following error:

> No error message available, result code: DB_E_ERRORSOCCURRED(0x80040E21).
>   Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>   Exception Details: System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException: No error message available, result code: DB_E_ERRORSOCCURRED(0x80040E21).

Comment: which line causes error?

Comment: How many columns does table masters1 have? Do you want to insert one concatenated string into one column or three strings into three columns?

Comment: You desperately need to parameterize your queries. The way this is coded is a textbook example of sql injection.

Answer (score 1):

Look like you are using OleDbConnection for SQL Server.

You want to [SqlConnection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection(v=vs.110).aspx) if you use SQL Server. For example,

```
using(var con = new SqlConnection(
     "Server=myServerAddress;Database=myDataBase;Trusted_Connection=True;"))
{
   var query = "insert statement ...";
   using(var cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con)){
      cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
      con.Open();
      ....
   }
}
```

You might want to look at the connection string format [here](https://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server/) too.

***FYI:*** Use the parameterize query to avoid SQL Injection attack.